# Bootsrap 4 Grid or Flex

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a form that looks like the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <textarea name="comment" class='form-control' placeholder='Type new comment here..'></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type='button'><span class="fa fa-times mr5"></span>Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt5" name='new_comment' type='submit'><span class="fa fa-plus mr5"></span>Save</button>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 4.  The thing is, I want this form to be the max width of its container - to have the textarea stretch and the buttons be a static width.  If I use the above, I get a big empty gap because the smallest col (col-1) is to wide for the buttons.  How can I have it fill the width of the screen with the button columns remaining a fixed width?

I have a feeling its using flex and d-flex but I cant manage to get it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `flex-grow-0` to buttons column:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <textarea name="comment" class='form-control' placeholder='Type new comment here..'></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col flex-grow-0">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type='button'><span class="fa fa-times mr5"></span>Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt5" name='new_comment' type='submit'><span class="fa fa-plus mr5"></span>Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to overlap the container on the right hand side though, anyway to make it fit the bounds of the container-fluid?

Comment: Hmm no, but it is on mine for some reason.  Must be extra CSS messing with it.

Comment: @Chud37 share the full code you are using here: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ah okay.  So When I use your above code the button size gets crushed, so I've got a min-width: 78px on the button, which makes it overlap.  I want the buttons to look nice beside the textbox, so I need to be able to manually set the size of the buttons.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jwh2q68r/ So the textarea has the correct margins on the left hand side but the buttons overlap the container boundries

Comment: @Chud37 this is due to the use of nested column which is logical. You can reset the margin of the nested row if you don't like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bwudna56/

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `.col` and use `d-flex` and `flex-grow-1`.
Then, you can also add a margin-left using `ml-3` to the buttons.

```
<div class="row mw-100">
    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
        <textarea name="comment" class='form-control' placeholder='Type new comment here..'></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type='button'><span class="fa fa-times mr5"></span>Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt5" name='new_comment' type='submit'><span class="fa fa-plus mr5"></span>Save</button>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the buttons container, you can set the width you want.

Comment: The rows are inside a container-flex, and they are going outside the boundaries of that container still.  I should have mentioned that in my question, sorry

Comment: In the row, there is a ``.mw-100`` that applies ``max-width: 100%``. It solves it for you?